# FtpWebRequest and foreign characters/utf-8 characters

Tags: utf-8, ftp, ftpwebrequest

When using FtpWebRequest to list files and folders, can I list names with foreign characters?

A file name with 3 Chinese characters will come accross as "???" when enumerating files with FtpWebRequest:

> -rwxr-xr-x   1 user  group               1800 Dec 22 16:13:10 ???

Am I doing something wrong, or does FtpWebRequest not support this?

my code is derived from the example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716.aspx

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: Are you certain it's coming across that way rather than getting converted to that when you try and print it?

Answer (score 0):

If its just a string, try to use Encoding.Convert() method which can convert the file name from ome encoding to another.  (Add System.Text)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye.aspx